# Add axes and label to an external picture

Tags: diagrams, plot, includegraphics, axis

I have this image plotted in Mathematica where the frame label looks very bad.

[image]

Is there a way to add the log-log axis in tex to overlap with the picture. Say I use this picture without the axes. How do I correctly add the axes and create something like the first picture within latex.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is sort of hard-adjusted, but it works

```
% in the preamble 
%    \include{tikz}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (3,3) node {\includegraphics[width=6cm, height=6cm]{DIAGRAMFILE}};
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Some axes around a bitmap plot}
\end{figure}
```

That is the basic version, you may unleash the full power of pgfplots-axis design. For example, replace the two arrows (`\draw[->]`) by the following axes

```
% in the preamble 
%    \include{pgfplots}
 \begin{axis}[
        width=7cm, 
        height=7cm,
        axis x line=center, 
        axis y line=middle, 
        xlabel={$x$},
        xmode=log,
        x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, right},
        ymode=log,
        ymin=1, ymax=1001,
        xmin=1, xmax=1001,
        domain=0:1000]
\end{axis}
```

By the axis properties `xtick` and `xticklabels` (same for *y*) you take control over the labeling.
Anyway, the coordinates must manually be tuned to the figure size, and I do not see a way to get this automatically done. May be it helps to refer to coordinates within the axes (`cs`).

Comment: Yeah that might work for the axis but then I won't be able to put those numerical values on x and y axes correctly. I would like to have those ticks from (0,2) in x-axis and (0,0.5) in y-axis at the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the chapter "4.3.7 Using External Graphics as Plot Sources" of the pgfplots documentation. This allows you to use images as plots and add axis etc to them (you'll need to fine tune the exact minimum/maximum values, below just some dummy values):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top,
    xlabel={$\chi$},
    ylabel={$\zeta$},
]
    \addplot graphics [
    ymin=0.0005, ymax=1,
    xmin=0.0005, xmax=1,
    ] {plot};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]